# Water is Chesed

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, water, chesed-kindness

I read somewhere that "according to the kabala, water represents Chesed (kindness)". Any one know a source for this, and what that means in layman's terms?

Comment: Not I. But maybe http://chabad.org/380796 will help you.

Comment: I believe this is the reason many types of Chassidim pour some water into their wine - something about tempering din with chesed. I don’t understand Kabbalah, but that’s the answer I was given. If someone can track down that minhag and its sources that might tell you what exactly this means.

Comment: @msh210 thanks but has no sources